# How to add table of content in Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using JasperSoft Studio. I am generating a report which having Chapter and sub-chapter also. but all these Chapter and Sub-Chapter configured in Sub-report.

How I can get all these Chapter and Sub-chapter name with link, page number in a table of content formatted in one page like a standard table of content of a document?

**EDIT:** Moved users answer to question (it should be an edit of the question)

Bookmarks are coming in jasperserver (in separate tab ) but not coming in report. In TOC all the field evaluationTime=report. Here is my TOC jrxml code .

```
<detail>
    <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{level} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report" hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
            <reportElement style="HeadingLabel1" x="0" y="5" width="470" height="20" uuid="379fcff2-021d-4761-a89a-eeb772723b1b">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></textFieldExpression>
            <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Auto" hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
            <reportElement style="HeadingIndex1" x="470" y="5" width="45" height="20" uuid="a31e80f3-f1fa-4643-adbe-77a61c7b9051">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} + $F{pageIndex} + 1]]></textFieldExpression>
            <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
    <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{level} == 2]]></printWhenExpression>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report" hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
            <reportElement style="HeadingLabel2" x="40" y="5" width="430" height="20" uuid="379fcff2-021d-4761-a89a-eeb772723b1b">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></textFieldExpression>
            <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Auto" hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
            <reportElement style="HeadingIndex2" x="470" y="5" width="45" height="20" uuid="a31e80f3-f1fa-4643-adbe-77a61c7b9051">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} + $F{pageIndex} + 1]]></textFieldExpression>
            <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report" hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
            <reportElement style="HeadingLabel2" x="20" y="5" width="20" height="20" uuid="ae12cafd-22e8-45ae-a1a7-8e00a8208cf0">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{level2Index} + "."]]></textFieldExpression>
            <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
    <band height="15" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{level} == 3]]></printWhenExpression>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report" hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
            <reportElement style="HeadingLabel3" x="40" y="0" width="430" height="15" uuid="379fcff2-021d-4761-a89a-eeb772723b1b">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></textFieldExpression>
            <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Auto" hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
            <reportElement style="HeadingIndex3" x="470" y="0" width="45" height="15" uuid="a31e80f3-f1fa-4643-adbe-77a61c7b9051">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} + $F{pageIndex} + 1]]></textFieldExpression>
            <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

EDIT: here is my main report jrxml.

```
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="TCD"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.create.bookmarks" value="true"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.book.group.cover.header" value="Cover and Table of Contents"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.book.group.cover.footer" value="Backcover"/>
<property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/"/>
<property name="ireport.jasperserver.user" value="jasperadmin"/>
<property name="ireport.jasperserver.report.resource" value="/reports/TCD_book_page_files/main_jrxml"/>
<property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/reports/TCD_book_page"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT 1 NO FROM DUAL]]>
</queryString>
<field name="NO" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<group name="cover">
    <groupHeader>
        <part evaluationTime="Report" uuid="56ab525c-754f-4f48-a52c-7cc23934be3d">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.bookmarks.data.source.parameter" value="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE"/>
            <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["TCD_book_page_toc.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </p:subreportPart>
        </part>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
<detail>
    <part uuid="5196d1c8-d060-450f-b9f5-9089918b7389">
        <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
            <subreportParameter name="REPORT_CONNECTION">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["TCD_Page.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
        </p:subreportPart>
    </part>
</detail>
```

Comment: Please you need to provide version of jasper report, your current jrxml (what have you tried), your current output, check out this for table of contents example.. http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/tableofcontents/

Comment: I am using TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio-6.1.1.final to print report and I am having one main report and multiple sub-report. In this case how can I get all the hyper-linked values into table of content ?

Comment: Have you tried jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/tableofcontents, what are your result?

Comment: Thanks Petter for your responce. I tried Sample reference/tableofcontaints. But my case is different. I am having one main report and multiple sub-report based on chapter and sub-chapter conditionally. I want to print table of content in main/parent/first report. So how I can add all bookmarks from sub-report to main report ?

Comment: I tried with report book, in jasper report table of content level is showing in tool tips but, when generating docx/pdf report,  in table of content area only lines are coming, any idea ?

Comment: So it works in preview?, in pdf can you see the bookmarks (use pdf viewer to display bookmarks)? (are you creating the bookmarks correctly), check that the TOC as evalutationTime=report and other components do not have this... hard to tell with out seeing you jrxml code..

Comment: I added the comment below with jrxml code.

Comment: The TOC is a subreport correct?, You have set the level on your bookmarks correct?

Comment: I deleted ans :). Its bit urgent, can you have a look to jrxml.

Comment: You have follwed the BookReport.jrxml example on how to included the TOC, pass the datasource, net.sf.jasperreports.print.create.bookmarks=true, in your main report...

Comment: I already check "Create Bookmark". is there anything else need to do to make net.sf.jasperreports.print.create.bookmarks=true ?

Comment: You need to set the property in the main report.... download the BookReport.jrxml that is the main report for the example and you can compare your code with this...

Comment: In question I added main page jrxml code.

Comment: And whats is exactly happening now, do you see parts of TOC or no parts.. (remember to compile your jrxml subreport, since your referencing jasper)

Comment: in bookmark of pdf/word all the bookmarks are available. But in TOC section only dotted lines coming with other report data.

Comment: Start debugging it: remove a printWhen expression on level to check the datasource.. <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="TocData"/>, what $F{label} do we have...corresponds to your anchorNameExpression?

Comment: $F{level} is your bookmarkLevel

Comment: All book marks are available in bookmark section in docx/pdf. How can I add those bookmarks with level into report and when I am generating report how I cam make it available ?

Comment: Your TOCData should be a datasource of all you bookmarks (inside your subreport) with $F{label} = anchorNameExpression && with $F{level}=bookmarkLevel (attribute on textField)... try to make the TOC less complex to debug it... (one detail band, with no prinOnWhenExpression, having a textfield with $F{label}  and one with $F{level}, so that you understand what you have in your datasource (which bookmarks you have and what level they have)....

Comment: Thank for your input. I am able to add table of content in report. But how I can get the bookmark label page no in TOC ?

Comment: I am able to generate table of content dynamically using report booK template. Thanks for your response Petter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/tableofcontents/ does work even if you have the bookmarks in your subreport's. (in example they are in subreport).

Some important notice:

> The main report should have the **net.sf.jasperreports.print.create.bookmarks** set in order to collect bookmarks at report generation time.
>
> The Table of Contents part needs to be **evaluated after** other report
>   parts; if the part is to be printed at the beginning of the document
>   it should have Report evaluation (and no subsequent parts should have
>   the same evaluation).

If you do not want to use this feature of jasper report, you need to generate your own scriplet to collect data see for example:

[how-can-i-build-a-table-of-contents-in-ireport-jasperreports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721857/how-can-i-build-a-table-of-contents-in-ireport-jasperreports)